# Swift - How do i get permission? Location Service , Photo Library etc

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, appdelegate, user-permissions

I have to get Permissions in App for sending and getting some Data. When I try to get a data I got some errors if permissions is not enabled.Therefore I try to get permissions in AppDelegate. **Is this a correct way?**.

Moreover, When request permission selection , If I exit from App suddenly and turn back again , Permissions always show pop-up " You dont have permission " and I redirect to "Settings/Permissions" because of checking control from AppDelegate. But Permission is not shown in Settings because I didnt install permission yet.
How do I do this permission issue. **Which is the best way to do this?**

// AppDelegate

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    let libStatus = GlobalVariables.defaults.object(forKey: "isCreatedAlbum") as? Bool

    if libStatus != true {
        PermissionsControl().library()
    }

}
```

// PermissionControl Library

```
func library(){

    let libraryAuth = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    var topWindow: UIWindow? = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    print("Library Authorization Status \(PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus().hashValue)")

    if libraryAuth == PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {

        topWindow?.isHidden = false // if you want to hide the topwindow then use this
        topWindow = nil // if you want to remove the topwindow then use this

        let permissionStatus = GlobalVariables.defaults.object(forKey: "isCreatedAlbum") as? Bool

        if permissionStatus != true {
            CustomPhotoAlbum().createAlbum()
            GlobalVariables.defaults.set(true, forKey: "isCreatedAlbum")
        }

    } else if libraryAuth == PHAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined || libraryAuth == PHAuthorizationStatus.denied {


        topWindow?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        topWindow?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
        let alert: UIAlertController =  UIAlertController(title: "Permission Error", message: "\nPlease give permission for Library!\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default , handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            // continue your work

            guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
                return
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            }

        }))

        topWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        topWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: App permissions are depends on your app functionality. It does not like whenever you want you ask user to get permission. Give more detail about your porject and its work flow.

Comment: There is a big difference between `.notDetermined` and `.denied`.  In the `.notDetermined` case you have never asked the user for permission and the appropriate action is to call `requestAuthorization`.  If the status is `.denied.` then you may wish to display an alert to open settings to give the user a chance to change the permission.

Comment: Hmmm. So when in .notDetermined status, I can show request permission alert again. Thank you sir. I know the differences of status but I didnt think this way.

Comment: Add what type of permission you want in your info.plist file.